# Count Email by sender outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server, office-automation

i have to do a macro for count email by sender

this is my code

```
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strSender As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim varSenders As Variant
    Dim varItemCounts As Variant
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
 
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 
    For i = objInbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If objInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
           Set objMail = objInbox.Items(i)
           strSender = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
 
           If objDictionary.Exists(strSender) Then
              objDictionary.Item(strSender) = objDictionary.Item(strSender) + 1
           Else
              objDictionary.Add strSender, 1
           End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcelApp.Visible = True
    Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    With objExcelWorksheet
         .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
         .Cells(1, 2) = "Count"
    End With
 
    varSenders = objDictionary.Keys
    varItemCounts = objDictionary.Items
 
    For i = LBound(varSenders) To UBound(varSenders)
        nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With objExcelWorksheet
             .Cells(nLastRow, 1) = varSenders(i)
             .Cells(nLastRow, 2) = varItemCounts(i)
        End With
    Next
 
    objExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End Sub
```

The problem is when i execute the code , i have this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQzym.png)

the error say : the underlying security system cannot find your digital ID

can you help me pls ?

Comment: Which line of your code causes that error?

Comment: It is strSender = objMail.SenderEmailAddress

Comment: Off-topic on this site. [Outlook: Your Digital ID Name Cannot Be Found](https://www.technipages.com/outlook-your-digital-id-name-cannot-be-found) and [Fix: “Your Digital ID name cannot be found by the underlying security system” on Microsoft Outlook?](https://appuals.com/your-digital-id-name-cannot-be-found-by-the-underlying-security-system/) and [Outlook certificate error: Digital ID name cannot be found by underlying security system](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-certificate-error-digital-id-name-cannot/1c36d919-91cf-4bc9-a7cc-aeb09ae37084)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all items in the folder:

```
 For i = objInbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If objInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to get only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you could use the following search criteria to get items from a specific sender's email address:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail" & Chr(34) _ 
& " = 'some@email.com'"
```

or better yet:

```
 Filter = "@SQL=" & " urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail Like '%some@email.com%'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information.

After you have applied a filter to the collection you may check out the `Count` property of the `Items` class which can give you the number of items from a specific sender.

If you need the latest received items from the folder you need to do the following:

1. [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) items in the `Items` collection by the received date.
2. Iterate over the last/first 10 items in the sorted collection.

A possible alternative is to get items for a specific date(s) using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class.

Comment: Me i want the top 10 of sender in all mail from the folder and not a specific sender

Comment: Use the `Sort` method of the Items class to get the items sorted, so you will get the latest items. See my post updated.